# CoreText note: warning on macOS when running Tkinter and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating a Tkinter app in python3 in macOS Catalina. The app is running fine but whenever a data is inserted into tk.Text, I get the following warning:

```
--> 2020-10-10 13:15:51.048 Python[2388:95658] CoreText note: Client requested name ".SFNSMono-Regular", it will get Times-Roman rather than the intended font. All system UI font access should be through proper APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[NSFont systemFontOfSize:].

-->2020-10-10 13:15:51.048 Python[2388:95658] CoreText note: Set a breakpoint on CTFontLogSystemFontNameRequest to debug.

-->2020-10-10 13:15:51.088 Python[2388:95658] CoreText note: Client requested name ".SF NS Mono", it will get Times-Roman rather than the intended font. All system UI font access should be through proper APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[NSFont systemFontOfSize:].
```

Despite these warnings, the code runs just fine. I want to hide these errors as I cannot find any solution to this. I have tried

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

But this does not solve the problem.
Any suggestions to hide the warnings would be a great help.

Below is the textbox that is causing the problem. I know that because when I comment out the textbox, the errors do not come.

```
lf = LabelFrame(root, text="Selected Value", width=100, height=80)
lf.place(x=20, y=600, anchor="w")
tx = Text(lf, wrap=WORD, padx=5, height=10, width=50)
tx.insert(INSERT, final_value)
tx.config(state=DISABLED)
scroll = Scrollbar(lf, orient=VERTICAL, command=tx.yview)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
tx.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
tx.pack()
```

Comment: is final_value is some kind of variable that gets updated every time if so then there would be an error. Since you have disabled the text box so create a function that set the state to enable when inserting text and after inserting reset it to disabled

Comment: But it works just fine when I run the script through an IDE or terminal. Even in alias mode.